# Batch file exits immediately upon selecting an option

Tags: batch-file

After Executing the file and choosing a number,the code exits without running the codes in the if statements.

I tried changing the quotes on the number variable but it didn't work.

```
 @echo off
 color 0a
 title Pick A number game
 cls
 echo Please enter number btw 1 and 5
 set /p number=number
 if "%number%" EQU 1( 
 start explorer
 )else if "%number%" EQU "2"(
 start control
)else if  "%number%" EQU "3"(
 start "" http://google.com
)else  start iexplore.exe
```

The code should execute one of the conditions within the statement.

Comment: Put a _space_ in front of every `(` and behind every `)`. Then in the first comparison when the user entered `1` you are comparing `"1"` with `1` which will never be equal. You could place `set /a number+=0` after `set /p` to ensure `number` is truly numeric, even when the user entered nothing or a string like `crap`; then remove all quotation marks in the comparison expressions to do true numeric comparisons. Or you go a different path and use [`choice`](https://ss64.com/nt/choice) which only allows certain key presses (like `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5` in your situation)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was the way the code was checking the answer. After simplifying and editing, the script launches the programs correctly.

```
@echo off
color 0a
title Pick A number game
cls
echo Please enter number between 0 and 5
set /p number=number: 
if %number%==1 start explorer
if %number%==2 start control
if %number%==3 start "" http://google.com
if %number%==4 start iexplore.exe
pause
```

Comment: Just to be explicit, `if "%number%" EQU 1` can never be true because of the double quotes.  After substituting the variable you would have `if "1" EQU 1` which is false.  I would personally still double quote the variable to avoid errors when someone just hits enter and the variable is then undefined. `if "%number%"=="1"`

Comment: Thanks for the better explanation. I personally don't use quotes around variables much because i didn't know how exactly, so I'm learning too. Thanks

Comment: As well as using the `if "%number%"=="1"` syntax , as already suggested I'd suggest `set /p "number=number: "` and to either remove the empty title when `start`ing the URL, or enclose the URL in doublequotes and leave the empty title as is.